# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,176525) (300,176525)

Tags: python, nlp

I have countVectors of 2 paragraphs of dimension (2,176525) and I want to multiply the learned weight vector of dimension (300,176525) with it.

I am using:

```
EmbeddedTrainParagraphs=np.multiply(EmbeddedTrainParagraphs,w)
```

But getting the error. Any suggestions?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Sorry, I am passed of that stage now and I didn't make notes of the error. But it was solved by the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.multiply()` do element-wise production. In your case you may need dot production:

```
A @ B.T
```

or

```
np.dot(A, B.T)
```

make sure the size match. The result is a 2 by 300 matrix.